# Finding determinant of $adjoint(A^{-1} )$

Tags: matrices, determinant

[image]

My attempt:

- For the first part I manipulated $A^{-1}=\frac {adj(A)}{det(A)}$ to
  arrive at $det A^{n-1}=det(adj(A))$. Then using the same formula I
  simply calculated $det(adj(A))$ since transposing $A$ wouldn't change
  it's determinant. Got $169$.
- Very confused about the second part but I did $(det(adj(A)))^{-1}$ to
  get $13$
- For the third I did $det(adj(A))$ x $5^3$-
- For the last part I just tracked back. Switched $-9$ and $8$, changed
  the sign on $1$ and $3$ and calculated the determinant with $ad-bc$.

What am I doing wrong?